# how to solve the Inedo Hub Proget installation error?

Tags: proget

i am trying to install proget on my 2012 server,
i am getting these error, this might be due to error in configuration
Please let me know the integration url and feed url..

[image]
[image]

Product: ProGet
Version: 5.1.15

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Configuration'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at Inedo.Hub.Data.InstalledProduct.g__readDbConfigValue|59_0(String key, <>c__DisplayClass59_0& ) in C:\InedoAgent\BuildMasterTemp\Temp_E80991\Src\src\InedoHubCore\Data\InstalledProduct.cs:line 161
   at Inedo.Hub.Data.InstalledProduct.ScrapeFromInstallation(String targetPath) in C:\InedoAgent\BuildMasterTemp\Temp_E80991\Src\src\InedoHubCore\Data\InstalledProduct.cs:line 151
ClientConnectionId:674594c1-dcf5-4bac-9fec-44a7a4756ba3
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16

Answer (score 0):

The integration URL in the Inedo Hub `[config]` should be `https://my.inedo.com/services/v1`.

To change the port ProGet listens on, use the Configuration tab after installing.

If ProGet was not previously successfully installed on this machine, deleting the file at `%ProgramData%\Inedo\SharedConfig\ProGet.config` will stop Inedo Hub from trying to read data from the database.